# How to set children to a route that's rendered at "/" in Remix?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, remix.run

I'm trying to migrate a React Router app to Remix.
Here's a basic example of how my React Router app works:
https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-chandrasekhar-fx0f7f

As you can see, I have a `MainComponent` which is rendered at "/" and it has an `Outlet` component from `react-router-dom` to render different headers based on the path.

By default, my `MainHeader` component renders there because its path is set to the same as its parent, so it also renders at "/".

But when I navigate to a dynamic route I'm rendering the `AnotherHeader` component instead of `MainHeader`.

I'm setting how the routing works in App.tsx with the `createBrowserRouter` function, where setting children to a component rendered at "/" is perfectly valid.

However, when I try to migrate this app to Remix I have no idea how to do that.

I created the following routes:

- app/routes/index.tsx:

  ```js
  import { MainComponent } from "../components";

  export default function Index() {
    return <MainComponent />;
  }
  ```
- app/routes/$id.tsx:

  ```js
  import { AnotherHeader } from "../components";

  export default function Another() {
    return <AnotherHeader />;
  }
  ```

I'm rendering it at the same "/" route as my main `MainComponent` which works great in `react-router-dom` but apparently [index routes cannot have child routes in Remix](https://remix.run/docs/en/1.16.1/guides/routing#index-routes).

I've created [a Remix version of the same app](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/fervent-faraday-2fyxqp), where you can hopefully see the differences, which lies in the fact that the `MainHeader` component doesn't render since I haven't created a route for it yet. Also when `AnotherHeader` renders, it doesn't render within the `MainComponent` but as a separate component.

So the question is
How can I create a route for my MainHeader component in Remix so that it works the same way as in my React Router app?

Comment: IIRC Remix uses the same routers that they export for use in `react-router`/`react-router-dom`. It's unclear what you are trying to do (*in code*) so it's unclear what any issue is. Can you [edit] to clarify what you are trying to accomplish and include a better [mcve]?

Comment: Can you share also the file structure you are trying to use for these pages?

Comment: I have included a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-chandrasekhar-fx0f7f) link in my question that shows how my React Router app works. I would like to create the same behavior in Remix [where routes are created in the `app/routes` folder](https://remix.run/docs/en/1.16.1/file-conventions/routes-files). I hope this clarifies the issue and thank you for taking your time to help!

Comment: Unfortunately, no, not really, the code in the sandbox isn't Remix and it's working. That said, in `react-router` it's more idiomatic to use the `index` prop instead of `path="..."` for the nested route that matches the parent route. Are you wanting `MainComponent` to just be a layout route, likely without a path? It kind of seems like you are mixing up these header components with actual routed content.

Comment: Yes, I also mentioned in the original question and here in the comments that this link shows how my **React Router app works**.  So I know it works, I've just created it quickly so I can show you what I have and what I want to migrate to Remix. I mentioned in the question that "I'm trying to migrate a React Router app to Remix." and also in my previous comment I mentioned that "I would like to create the same behavior in Remix". I hope it helps clarifying the issue.

Comment: So the main question is
How can I create a route for my MainHeader component in Remix so that it works the same way as in my React Router app?

Comment: Can you [edit] to share what and how you are trying to do this using Remix then? Remix, from what I understand, will use the file/directory structure and naming convention to establish the routing structure. This is completely different than using `react-router`/`react-router-dom` client-side using JSX.

Comment: Yes, it is completely different and that's why I have problems XD The components are exactly the same as in my React Router app. I went through the [Remix migration guide](https://remix.run/docs/en/1.16.1/guides/migrating-react-router-app) and did everything accordingly. The only difference is that I have set up routes in my app/routes folder that you can see at the bottom of my question.

Comment: Just a guess based on the docs, but maybe try renaming the `MainComponent` file from `/app/routes/index.tsx` to `/app/root.tsx`, and then the `MainHeader` component file to `/app/routes/_index.tsx` so it's the index route of the "root". Can you [edit] to add the file/directory structure you are using? Also, fix the header component files so they are not redeclaring the header component they are importing.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to use routing where at "/" I render `MainComponent` and also `MainHeader` as its child, so for that I have to create a route, which I did. I edited the question and included a link to a Remix version of what I have. [app/root.tsx](https://remix.run/docs/en/1.16.1/guides/migrating-react-router-app#creating-the-root-route) is something different. "Its default export is a component that renders the full HTML tree that every other route loads and depends on."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `react-router-dom` version of your code, it's the more idiomatic convention to specify the `index` prop for the nested route you want to be rendered when the path *exactly* the parent route than it is to specify a `path` prop with the same path value.

Example:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <MainComponent />,
    children: [
      {
        index: true, // <-- match with parent route path
        element: <MainHeader />
      },
      {
        path: "/:id",
        element: <AnotherHeader />
      }
    ]
  }
]);
```

or

```
<Route path="/" element={<MainComponent />}>
  <Route index element={<MainHeader />} />
  <Route path=":id" element={<AnotherHeader />} />
</Route>
```

All routing is assumed to be from "root", e.g. `"/"` in most/common cases. The `MainComponent` is the root-level component being rendered as a layout route.

[Defining Routes](https://remix.run/docs/en/1.16.1/guides/routing#defining-routes)

Based on the docs I believe the following is the file/directory structure to convert the `react-router-dom` code to a Remix version:

```
app
+-- root.tsx      // <-- file that renders MainComponent, e.g. UI + Outlet
+-- routes
    +-- index.tsx // <-- file that renders MainHeader
    +-- $id.tsx   // <-- file that renders AnotherHeader
```

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/quirky-leftpad-s1xqfn?file=%2Fapp%2Froot.tsx%3A6%2C10

[image: main root page]
[image: page id 1]
[image: page id 2]

Comment: Do you mind editing the [Remix version of what I have currently](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/fervent-faraday-2fyxqp)? I honestly appreciate your intent to help but now I'm not 100% sure of what exactly I should change so if you could share a sandbox with your modifications that would help a lot!

Comment: @ThomasSoos I've not worked with Remix much, so hopefully this [fork](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/quirky-leftpad-s1xqfn?file=%2Fapp%2Froot.tsx%3A6%2C10) of your sandbox works for what you are looking to accomplish. Changes: (1) `/app/root.tsx` renders `MainComponent` instead of `Outlet`, (2) `/app/routes/index.tsx` renders `MainHeader` instead of `MainComponent`.

Comment: I've not worked with Remix much either, otherwise this wouldn't have caused me this much trouble :-) And yes, this is exactly what I was trying to achieve but replacing the `Outlet` component with my `MainComponent` has never crossed my mind for some reason. I guess because all their examples included it in the `app/root.tsx` file. Thanks a lot for your help!